# Automatically remove gaps in primary key sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key

I am creating a webpage. This webpage stores data into a MySQL database based on the users actions. The database has many rows. The primary key of the row is the column rowID and it just numbers the rows in order (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4....). The user has the option to delete rows. The problem is that when the user deletes rows other than the last row. There is a skip in the rowID. For example, if there are 5 rows, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 and the user deletes the third row. Now the data in the rowID column is 1, 2, 4, 5. I wanted to know if there is already a built in function in MySQL or PHP to account efficiently for this.

The only way I know to get rid of this is to loop through the rows and refresh the rowID basically. However I feel this would be very costly in terms of time if there are a large number of rows.

I also wanted to know how to autoincrement the rowID if there are new rows being created. Currently I have code to find the current greatest rowNumber and insert a row with the current greatest rowNumber+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do that. The primary key is the unique identifier and should never change once created. What you're looking for is [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). Add a field to keep track of the left_id and right_id and manually update that if you must. There are libraries in Doctrine2 that handle this for you.

If you absolutely MUST make this change, you can use alter table to drop the field and then re-add it.

Comment: So from what I understand, a solution would be to create another column identical to the primary key (however not being the primary key) and update that instead? Also could you elaborate on the left_id and right_id solution as I am not sure I understand it.

Comment: It is one *viewpoint* that the PK should never change. But SQL supports cascading specially for this "problem" and there is nothing inherently wrong with a PK that can change - of course, there *is* likely a problem with changing the PK just for the sake of maintaining a non-gapped sequence as described by the OP ..

Comment: From your example if the 3rd item is deleted. The first row left_id = 0, right_id = 2| the second row left_id = 1, right_id=4| the fourth row left_id = 2, right_id = 5| fifth row left_id = 4, right_id = null

Comment: For much easier management of this kind of data, check out: https://github.com/blt04/doctrine2-nestedset

Answer (score 3):

No there isnt because its not important. You should not be depending on the primary key being a contiguous sequence. Its only function is to ensure the key is a unique identifier for the row, beyond that the numbers have no meaning.

Comment: +1 I would write the same answer - perhaps in more detail - but ultimately it would say no more than this. If a non-gapped sequence needed, that can usually be done as a view operation on the select (or an emulation of such) - the database itself doesn't care otherwise.